# No references or bibliography is appearing for Thesis format

Tags: biblatex

This is my code, where after searching a lot and working around. I couldn't seem to resolve my problem. 
Really sorry for this trivial problem

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{breqn}


\colorlet{linkequation}{red}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\field}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}%

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesisbib.bib}
\title{
    {My most productive work}\\
    {\large Institute}\\
    {}
}
\author{Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\chapter*{Dedication}
To mum and dad

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare this and that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I want to thank you all...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{introduction}

\chapter{Experiments}
\input{chapter02/chapter02}

\chapter{Theory 1}
\input{chapter03/chapter03}

\chapter{Theory 2}
\input{chapter04/chapter04}

\chapter{Theory 3}
\input{chapter05/chapter05}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{conclusion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output doesn't seem to give any bibliography. I'm using `\parencite` in order to cite my references.

```
The error I'm getting.      
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018)
The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Thesis.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Question: After running LaTeX, do you run biber followed by another LaTeX run?

Comment: I have a `.bbl` file which I used `bib latex` complitation. And for my original code. I used the order of compile `Pdflatex Pdflatex Biblatex Pdflatex`. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: You should be running `biber`, not `biblatex`. Actually, I'm surprised that you don't get an error message related to the fact that there is no executable program called `biblatex`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I used your idea and spending some time to implement and correct some errors. But this error doesn't seem to go away. `BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/wl/z407g2c93tv4cncpjn__pm0m0000gn/T/zAvwOWoWMV/thesisbib.bib_71981.utf8, line 1, syntax error: found "}", expected ","`

Comment: @Mico I tried going through each references (very painful job). But I don't know where I'm lost

Comment: There seem to be two distinct and separate issues that need to be solved. First, one or more of the entries in the file `thesisbib.bib` would appear to contain syntax errors, such as missing commas. Second, since you load the `biblatex` package without the option `backend=bibtex`, you should *not* be running bibtex; instead, you should be running a program called `biber`.

Comment: @Mico It resolved my problem. Thanks a lot